# How to display protocol view in a SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a protocol for an object as such:

```
public protocol Viewable {
    associatedtype Content: View

    var parent: (any Viewable)? { get }
    var body: Content { get }
}
```

What I would like is to show the body of the view inside of another view, something like this:

```
public struct SampleView: View {
    
    var object: (any Viewable)?
    
    public var body: some View {
        object!.body 
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error *Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'*

What would be the best way to show a view of an object which was defined in a protocol extension ***without using AnyView***?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `object` cannot be an existential type (a dynamically typed protocol) because the protocol requirements for `View` specify the [`View.Body`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/body-swift.associatedtype) is a generic, associated type.

We need to retain the full, generic type information in order to satisfy the `some View` requirement for `body` on `View`.
The answer is to use a concrete generic type:

```swift
public struct SampleView: View {
    
    var object: (some Viewable)?
    
    public var body: some View {
        object!.body 
    }
}
```

For clarity, this can be spelled more traditionally to make it clear this is a generically constrained type to your custom protocol:

```swift
public struct SampleView<T: Viewable>: View {
    
    var object: T?
    
    public var body: some View {
        object!.body
    }
}
```

This behaviour is detailed more in the proposal for [SE-0309](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md) which originally allowed existential types to be used for any protocol type.

---

To still use `Viewable` types heterogeneously (such as in an Array), you'll need to create an additional layer of abstraction, such as creating an `enum` with concrete values as associated values.

```swift
struct SampleView: Viewable { ... }
struct ProfileView: Viewable { ... }
struct PreferencesView: Viewable { ... }

enum Views {
   case sample(SampleView)
   case profile(ProfileView)
   case preferences(PreferencesView)
}

var views = [Views]()
```

Now you can access the concrete types in the associated values.
Obviously this solution does not scale as well though, and this kind of approach to dealing with generic types should be used in limited circumstances to avoid this `enum` becoming very large with many cases.

Comment: What if I have an array of Viewable objects? Swift is forcing me to pass them as any Viewable, which does not work if I want place object from array into a that SampleView. Is there a way where I can do so? ie. Converting any Viewable into Viewable.

Comment: You'll need to create an additional layer of abstraction to fit your needs and work around this limitation. You could use an `enum` with strongly-typed associated values to hold the concrete values, for example.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a small example, I am not completely sure how an enum would work in this case. If I have an array: var objects = [any Viewable](). Then I would like to place the last object from array into a SampleView(objects.last). Thank you!

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Comment: Or just use [`AnyView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyview). It exists for a reason.